# Consulta realtime database firebase desde flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, realtime-database

Tengo una base de datos de la biblia en realtime database de firebase, la cual consulto desde flutter por medio de un service, cuando hago la consulta este me trae toda la biblia, sin embargo quiero ajustarlo de tal forma que solo me consulte determinado libro y no me traiga toda la biblia completa, esto para poder disminuir los tiempos de carga y los consumos de la aplicación, existe alguna forma de indicarle al archivo de service el libro especifico que quiero consultar?

Estructura de la base de datos

```
{
    "Biblia": {
        "libro1": {
            "capitulo1": {
                "versiculo1": "Texto",
                "versiculo2": "Text",
                "...": "..."
            },
            "capitulo2": {
                "...": "..."
            }
        },
        "libro2": {
            "...": "..."
        },
        "...": "..."
    }
}
```

Archivo de service:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bible/models/models.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class BibleService extends ChangeNotifier {

  final String _baseUrl = 'example-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com';
  final List<Book> books = [];
  bool isLoading = true;

  BibleService() {
    loadBooks();
  }

  Future loadBooks() async {
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    final url = Uri.https(_baseUrl, 'Biblia.json');
    final res = await http.get(url);

    final Map<String, dynamic>? booksMap = json.decode(res.body);

    booksMap?.forEach((key, value) {
      final tempBook = Book.fromMap(value);
      tempBook.id = key;
      books.add(tempBook);
    });

    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return books; //print(books[0].capitulo1?.versiculo1);
  }
}
```

Modelo:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Book {
  Book({
    this.capitulo1,
    this.capitulo2,
    this.capitulo3,
    this.capitulo4,
    this.capitulo5,
  });

  Capitulo? capitulo1;
  Capitulo? capitulo2;
  Capitulo? capitulo3;
  Capitulo? capitulo4;
  Capitulo? capitulo5;

  String? id;

  factory Book.fromJson(String str) => Book.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  factory Book.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Book(
        capitulo1: json["capitulo 1"] == null ? null : Capitulo.fromMap(json["capitulo 1"]),
        capitulo2: json["capitulo 2"] == null ? null : Capitulo.fromMap(json["capitulo 2"]),
        capitulo3: json["capitulo 3"] == null ? null : Capitulo.fromMap(json["capitulo 3"]),
        capitulo4: json["capitulo 4"] == null ? null : Capitulo.fromMap(json["capitulo 4"]),
        capitulo5: json["capitulo 5"] == null ? null : Capitulo.fromMap(json["capitulo 5"]),
      );
}

class Capitulo {
  Capitulo({
    this.versiculo1,
    this.versiculo2,
    this.versiculo3,
    this.versiculo4,
    this.versiculo5,
  });

  String? versiculo1;
  String? versiculo2;
  String? versiculo3;
  String? versiculo4;
  String? versiculo5;

  factory Capitulo.fromJson(String str) => Capitulo.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  factory Capitulo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Capitulo(
        versiculo1: json["versiculo 1"],
        versiculo2: json["versiculo 2"],
        versiculo3: json["versiculo 3"],
        versiculo4: json["versiculo 4"],
        versiculo5: json["versiculo 5"],       
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta con agregar el libro que quieras al endpoint, de esta forma:

```
  Future loadBooks(int index) async {
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    final url = Uri.https(_baseUrl, 'Biblia/libro$index.json'); 
    final res = await http.get(url);

    final Map<String, dynamic>? booksMap = json.decode(res.body);

    booksMap?.forEach((key, value) {
      final tempBook = Book.fromMap(value);
      tempBook.id = key;
      books.add(tempBook);
    });

    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return books; //print(books[0].capitulo1?.versiculo1);
  }
```

Comment: ¿Puedo enviar el string 'Biblia/libroX.json' por parámetros o seria necesario crear un service por cada libro?

Comment: Puedes. Ahora edito la respuesta para que veas como

Comment: Si te ha ayudado no olvides marcarla como correcta por favor